# Homomorphism between $\mathbb C^*$ and $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> I want to know that if there is any nontrivial homomorphism between $\mathbb C^*$ , the group of all non zero complex numbers and $S_n$ , the group of all permutations on the set   $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$   $(n \ge 2) $ or  $A_n$ , the set of all even permutations on the same set.

Any insight . Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi:\mathbb C^* \longmapsto S_n$ be a homomorphism. Then $\mathbb C^*/ker\phi \cong H\le S_n$. i.e. $ker\phi $ is a finite index subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$. Let $\mid \mathbb C^*:ker\phi \mid=n\Rightarrow x^n\in ker\phi $ $\forall x\in \mathbb C^*$.

Now the equation $x^n=c$ has solution of $x$ for every $x\in \mathbb C^*\Rightarrow \mathbb C^*\subseteq ker\phi \Rightarrow ker\phi =\mathbb C^*$. Hence the only homomorphism is the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: I didn't get the 2nd paragraph ! Will you explain please.

Comment: If $c\ne 0$ then $c=r(cos(\theta )+isin(\theta )),$ for some $r\in \mathbb R^+$ and $\theta \in \mathbb R$. In that case we find that if $x=\sqrt[n]{r}(cos(\frac{\theta }{n})+isin(\frac{\theta }{n}))$ then $x^n=c\in ker \phi$. So $ker \phi $ contains $\mathbb C^*$

Comment: Actually I have a bizzare view of the map, so thats why $x^n = c \in ker \phi$ , is not getting me right..

Comment: I got it right.Now it's clear.Btw thanks for your answer ..

Answer (score 6):

(There may be an easier way to see this.)

There are no such nontrivial homomorphisms. Since $\mathbb C^*$ is a [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) and every quotient of a divisible group is again divisible, by the first isomorphism theorem the image of such a homomorphism is divisible too. But the only finite divisible group is the trivial group, so every homomorphism is trivial.

Comment: Yes, there may be an easier way to see this... but I doubt it.

Comment: This argument is elementary enough that nobody should be worrying about finding an "easier" way.

Comment: I didn't know about the divisible group ! But your answer is fine.I am ok with it.Still I have a question , what if the domain is interchanged with the codomain ? @tschih

Comment: This seems pretty easy.

Comment: Will you please let me know then @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @Hiren Garai: I think Thomas' comment refers to my answer. As for your question, you should probably post it as a separate question. There are some cases to consider.

Comment: Oh ! Ok I am posting.