# Homomorphism from the group of permutation to the group of non zero complex numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

The question I am asking is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2418389/384535).

My question is what  if the codomain is interchanged with the domain. i.e is there any nontrivial homomorphism between the permutation group  (the group of even permutations) of $n(n \ge 2)$ elements and the the group of nonzero complex numbers ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The homomorphisms from a group $G$ to an abelian group $A$ are in one-to-one correspondence with homomorphisms to $A$ from the *abelianization* $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ of $G$.

We have (according to wikipedia):

- $S_1^{\mathrm{ab}} = 0$
- $S_n^{\mathrm{ab}} = \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 2$
- $A_3^{\mathrm{ab}} \cong A_4^{\mathrm{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$
- $A_n^{\mathrm{ab}} = 0$ for $n \neq 3,4$

and its easy to find nontrivial homomorphisms from nontrivial cyclic groups to $\mathbb{C}^\times$. For finite ones, think of the roots of unity.

Comment: So the homomorphis are unique ? @Hurkyl